# ¿Cómo deserealizar un json php a visual basic.net escritorio?

Tags: php, mysql, json, vb.net

```
 $server->register('orden_pedido', // Nombre de la funcion

                    array('fecha' => 'xsd:string'), // Parametros de entrada

                    array('return' => 'xsd:string'), // Parametros de salida

                    $url);

                    function orden_pedido($fecha){

        //recibo el dato enviado por el celular, ahora pongo un mensaje en la variable_accion

        $encontro="No";


        $sql = "select a.idordenar_pedido,a.fecha,c.idusuario,c.nombre,a.total from ordenar_pedido a,ventas b,usuario c,producto d where a.idventas=b.idventas and a.idproducto= d.idproducto and a.idusuario=c.idusuario and a.fecha='$fecha'";//string que almacena l aconsulta a ejecutar
        $resul = mysql_query($sql);
        $data = array();
        while($datos = mysql_fetch_row($resul))
        {
            $data[]= $datos[0];

        }
        //print_r($data); 

        return new soapval('return','xsd:string',json_encode($data));
        //return new soapval('return','xsd:string',$data);
    }
```

//Esto me retorna el json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en realidad no te retorna un json , es un string, lo que debes hacer es parsear ese string a formato json

Comment: No, no es un Json, tampoco es una cadena (string) lo que estás viendo del resultado es un formato XML. Lo que debes hacer es "parsear" a XML desde Visual Basic .net

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí un ejemplo:

El siguiente archivo XML será "parseado"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<family>
  <name gender="Male">
    <firstname>Tom</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
  </name>
  <name gender="Female">
    <firstname>Dale</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
  </name>
</family>
```

Te presento `XMLTextReader`

El uso de XmlTextReader es apropiado cuando la estructura del archivo XML es relativamente sencilla. El análisis con XmlTextReader te da una sensación de pre. net mientras caminas secuencialmente por el archivo usando los métodos Read () y obtienes datos usando GetAttribute () y ReadElementString (). Por lo tanto, mientras se utiliza XmlTextReader, el desarrollador debe realizar un seguimiento del archivo Xml y de Read () correctamente.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Module ParsingUsingXmlTextReader
Sub Main()
  Dim m_xmlr As XmlTextReader
  'Create the XML Reader
  m_xmlr = New XmlTextReader("C:\Personal\family.xml")
  'Disable whitespace so that you don't have to read over whitespaces
  m_xmlr.WhiteSpaceHandling = WhiteSpaceHandling.NONE
  'read the xml declaration and advance to family tag
  m_xmlr.Read()
  'read the family tag
  m_xmlr.Read()
  'Load the Loop
  While Not m_xmlr.EOF
    'Go to the name tag
    m_xmlr.Read()
    'if not start element exit while loop
    If Not m_xmlr.IsStartElement() Then
      Exit While
    End If
    'Get the Gender Attribute Value
    Dim genderAttribute = m_xmlr.GetAttribute("gender")
    'Read elements firstname and lastname
    m_xmlr.Read()
    'Get the firstName Element Value
    Dim firstNameValue = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("firstname")
    'Get the lastName Element Value
    Dim lastNameValue = m_xmlr.ReadElementString("lastname")
    'Write Result to the Console
    Console.WriteLine("Gender: " & genderAttribute _
      & " FirstName: " & firstNameValue & " LastName: " _
      & lastNameValue)
    Console.Write(vbCrLf)
  End While
  'close the reader
  m_xmlr.Close()
End Sub
End Module
```

Y aquí otra opción: `Parsing XML con XmlDocument`

La clase XmlDocument se modela según el modelo de objeto de documento. La clase XmlDocument es apropiada si necesita extraer datos de forma no secuencial.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Module ParsingUsingXmlDocument
Sub Main()
  Try
    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_node As XmlNode
    'Create the XML Document
    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
    'Load the Xml file
    m_xmld.Load("C:\CMS\Personal\family.xml")
    'Get the list of name nodes 
    m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/family/name")
    'Loop through the nodes
    For Each m_node In m_nodelist
      'Get the Gender Attribute Value
      Dim genderAttribute = m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("gender").Value
      'Get the firstName Element Value
      Dim firstNameValue = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
      'Get the lastName Element Value
      Dim lastNameValue = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
      'Write Result to the Console
      Console.Write("Gender: " & genderAttribute _
        & " FirstName: " & firstNameValue & " LastName: " _
        & lastNameValue)
      Console.Write(vbCrLf)
    Next
  Catch errorVariable As Exception
    'Error trapping
    Console.Write(errorVariable.ToString())
  End Try
End Sub
End Module
```

Sea cual sea el camino ninja elegido, el resultado es el esperado:

```
Gender: Male FirstName: Tom LastName: Smith

Gender: Female FirstName: Dale LastName: Smith
```

Ejemplo extraído de: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/XML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET